# Combine 2 tables order by date

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, these are the sample below.

[image]

I want to join them into one mysql query, ordering by date of both (**tbl1_date** and **tbl2_date**). The result what I want could be like this picture.

[image]

How is the query?? Thanks before.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I don't know what is the right query. I have tried JOIN but the result is not what I want. It was wrong

Comment: Are you familiar with `union all`?

Comment: If you want to recreate use `SELECT * FROM table_1 UNION SELECT * FROM table_2`. But what would be the point of having two tables with the same columns. Is it not possible to put the data in one table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no I am not

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2798e/1

Comment: wow it's new case for me. New lesson, new knowledge. Could you write an answer @Mr.Radical ?

Comment: @AldiUnanto placed it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

For descending:

```
select * FROM table_1
UNION
select * FROM table_2
ORDER BY tbl1_date DESC;
```

For ascending:

```
select * FROM table_1
UNION
select * FROM table_2
ORDER BY tbl1_date ASC;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 
    (
     tbl1_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     mat_id int, 
     tbl1_desc varchar(30),
     tbl1_date date
    );

INSERT INTO table_1
(mat_id, tbl1_desc, tbl1_date)
VALUES
(2,'Lorem','2014-01-02'),
(4, 'Ipsum','2014-01-10');


CREATE TABLE table_2 
    (
     tbl2_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     mat_id int, 
     tbl2_desc varchar(30),
     tbl2_date date
    );

INSERT INTO table_2
(mat_id, tbl2_desc, tbl2_date)
VALUES
(2,'Sit','2014-01-16'),
(4, 'Amet','2014-01-12');
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2798e/11)

Comment: `select * FROM table_1
UNION
select * FROM table_2
ORDER BY tbl1_date ;`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2798e/7

Comment: @AldiUnanto with "The newer is top" you mean? Descending? ADD DESC.

Comment: ouh no, I am sorry. I mean 'bottom'.

Comment: @AldiUnanto in that case add ACS.

Comment: Yep. synchronization errors between the thought with what was written